# Is it possible to register a user and submit a comment with one form with Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, registration, hook

Is it possible to do both registering for an account and submit a comment at the same time? I want the user to be able to do this all on one page to ecourage the registration rather than be discouraged about typing something, not realizing they had to be registered and thus having to leave the page.

I think that this could be done by adding register user action to the submit comment action, but not sure how to do it with the prebuilt wordpress add_action or do_action functions. Has anyone tried this, or know of any plug-ins that do this already? I searched but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's surely possible.

You must first familiarize yourself with the API.

Create your user using the `WP_CREATE_USER` function:

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

It will return the `USER ID` upon successful registration, then you will want to use the `WP_INSERT_COMMENT` function to add a comment to a post.

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to keep prospective commenters in the same place without sending them off to a registration page you might consider using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to bring a lightbox-style registration section up over the comments.  This isn't quite what you're looking for (i.e. submitting a comment and registration with one click), but it does get both actions to effectively take place in the same page and it can look pretty good too.